# Mongo: Storing time series measurement data

Tags: mongodb

We store temperature measurement data at every interval， we want to keep only 90 previous data. Our data structure would be like that:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("xxx"), "device" : "deviceId1", "count": 2, "values" : 
  [ 
    { "ts" : NumberLong("1471077454902"), "measureData" : 37.3 },
    { "ts" : NumberLong("1471077454911"), "measureData" : 37.4 } 
  ] 
}
```

count is the size of the values, for example when the array has 2 elements, then the size is 2. 
We design the Java API as follows:

```
 When the new measurement data comes:
   Get corresponding device id count:
       if count < 90:
             Push the new mesaure data into values and increase count by 1                
       if count >90:
             Pull the first element of the array and push the latest data into array.
  Store the first element pulled into history collection.
```

Is there one query or one aggregate could do these steps? Or shall we do this by traditional methed, say query, evaluate, then either push or pull/push.

//
//***************part 2 Traditional methods ***************//

```
public class TSDesignMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MongoClient mClient = new MongoClient();
        MongoDatabase db = mClient.getDatabase(MongoTSConstants.dbname);

        long tWarmingStart = System.nanoTime();
        InsertingWarmingDocument(db);
        long tWarmingEnd = System.nanoTime();
        double tDurationWarming = (double) (tWarmingEnd-tWarmingStart) / 1000/1000;
        System.out.println("warming db, insert 10000 document per event duration is "+tDurationWarming+"ms");


        long tInsert1Dev1DocStart = System.nanoTime();
        for(int j=1;j<10000;j++){
            storeMeasureDataIntoDB(db);
        }    
        long tInsert1Dev1DocEnd = System.nanoTime();
        double tInsert1Dev1DocDuration = (double) (tInsert1Dev1DocEnd-tInsert1Dev1DocStart) / 1000/1000;
        System.out.println("insert 10000 document in 90*24*30 elements array duration is "+tInsert1Dev1DocDuration+"ms");   


        long tQuery1Dev1DocStart = System.nanoTime();
        for(int j=1;j<10000;j++){
            handleQueryDocument(db);
        }    
        long tQuery1Dev1DocEnd = System.nanoTime();
        double tQuery1Dev1DocDuration = (double) (tQuery1Dev1DocEnd-tQuery1Dev1DocStart) / 1000/1000;
        System.out.println("query 10000 times in 90*24*30 elements array duration is "+tQuery1Dev1DocDuration+"ms");   


        mClient.close();               

    }

    private static void InsertingWarmingDocument(MongoDatabase db) {

        long ts = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        for(long i=1;i<100;i++){
            db.getCollection(MongoTSConstants.tsDataPdCollection).insertOne( 
                new Document(MongoTSConstants.deviceFn,MongoTSConstants.deviceIdPrefix+i+"test")
                     .append(MongoTSConstants.tsFn,ts+i)        
                );
        }    
    }

    private static void handleQueryDocument(MongoDatabase db) {
        Document where = new Document(MongoTSConstants.deviceFn,MongoTSConstants.deviceIdPrefix+1); 
        FindIterable<Document> it = db.getCollection(MongoTSConstants.tsDataInOneCollection).find(where);
        MongoCursor<Document> cur = it.iterator();

        int i=0;

        if(!cur.hasNext()){
             Document doc = cur.next();
             ArrayList<Document> obj = (ArrayList<Document>) doc.get("values");           
        }

    }



    private static void storeMeasureDataIntoDB(MongoDatabase db) {
        Document where = new Document(MongoTSConstants.deviceFn,MongoTSConstants.deviceIdPrefix+1); 
        FindIterable<Document> it = db.getCollection(MongoTSConstants.tsDataInOneCollection).find(where);
        MongoCursor<Document> cur = it.iterator();

        int i=0;


        /**
         * There is no device document in DB, insert new one. and use update to store 1st measure data 
         * 
         */
        if(!cur.hasNext()){
            long tsInsert = System.nanoTime();
            /**
             * insert device id
             */
            db.getCollection(MongoTSConstants.tsDataInOneCollection).insertOne(
                        new Document(MongoTSConstants.deviceFn,MongoTSConstants.deviceIdPrefix+1)
                            .append(MongoTSConstants.countFn,0));
            /**
             * using update to insert values array (store the first measure data)
             * 
             */                 
            db.getCollection(MongoTSConstants.tsDataInOneCollection).updateOne(
                        new Document(MongoTSConstants.deviceFn,MongoTSConstants.deviceIdPrefix+1),
                        new Document("$push", new Document("values",new Document(MongoTSConstants.tsFn,tsInsert).
                                 append(MongoTSConstants.measureDataFn,37.1)))
                        .append("$inc", new Document(MongoTSConstants.countFn,1)));
        }else{      
            while(cur.hasNext()){
                /**
                 * if i > 1, it means there are two doc with same device id, error!!
                 */
                if(i>=1){
                //log error find two docs with same devicedID.
                break;
                }

                Document doc = cur.next();
                Integer count = doc.getInteger("count");    

                /**
                 * measure data has over 3 month. 
                 */
                if( count >= MongoTSConstants.queryDataLength ){

                     /**
                      * get the first one in the array
                      */
                     ArrayList<Document> obj = (ArrayList<Document>) doc.get("values");                  
                     Document doc1Elem = (Document) obj.get(0);

                     /**
                      * pull the first one in the array
                      */                     
                     db.getCollection(MongoTSConstants.tsDataInOneCollection).updateOne(where,
                             new Document("$pop", -1));
                     long ts = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

                     /**
                      * push the new one 
                      */
                     db.getCollection(MongoTSConstants.tsDataInOneCollection).updateOne(where,
                            new Document("$push", new Document("values",new Document(MongoTSConstants.tsFn,ts).
                                                                                 append(MongoTSConstants.measureDataFn,37.8))));
                     //Store doc1Elem in another history collection;                     
                     db.getCollection(MongoTSConstants.tsHistoryCollection).insertOne(doc1Elem);
                }else{
                    /**
                     * Measure data has not reach 3 month data 
                     */
                    long ts = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();                     
                    db.getCollection(MongoTSConstants.tsDataInOneCollection).updateOne(where,
                            new Document("$push", new Document("values",new Document(MongoTSConstants.tsFn,ts).
                           append(MongoTSConstants.measureDataFn,37.9))).append("$inc", new Document(MongoTSConstants.countFn,1)));                     
                }          
                i++;
            }
        }       
    }  
}
```

Comment: I am using Mongo java api 3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, it is very difficult to do that currently(The latest version of mongodb is v3.2 at this moment.) and I have no idea how to achieve the goal.

## Explanation

#### I. Overview

There are 5 operations here and you want to **merge them into 1 update operation**:

1. Query by **deviceId**
2. Evaluation on **count** (count < 90 or count >= 90 ?)
3. Push a new data into the tail of **values** array
4. Pop the oldest data out of **values** array (optional, based on step 2)
5. **count** + 1 (optional, based on step 2)

Let's divide them into 2 parts: **Query part** & **update part**

#### II. Query part: Merge Query(1st) and Evaluation(2nd)?

Since I don't know how to put **Evaluation** into the **update action** part of an update statement:

```
db.test.update(
    {/* Query criteria */},
    {/* Update action */}
)
```

I made another approach - to put the **Evaluation** into the **Query criteria** part like this:

```
// We call this statement as UPDATE_STAT_1
db.test.update(
    {device: 'deviceId1', count: {$lt: 90}},
    {/* Update action: push new data to values and increase count */}
);
```

If the **count < 90**, your sample document will be matched & perform the update action(Don't care whether the update action succeed or fail at this moment).
And then mongoDB will return the execution result to you:

```
// Matched and updated
WriteResult({ 
    "nMatched" : 1,
    "nUpserted" : 0, 
    "nModified" : 1 
});
```

The result tells you that one document is matched and updated(nMatched = 1 & nModified = 1)

On the other hand, if the **count >= 90**, nothing will be matched and updated, the execution result will be:

```
// Not Matched
WriteResult({ 
    "nMatched" : 0, 
    "nUpserted" : 0, 
    "nModified" : 0 
})
```

So you will know that the count reaches 90, and you should perform another update statement:

```
// We call this statement as UPDATE_STAT_2
db.test.update(
    {device: 'deviceId1', count: {$gte: 90}},
    {/* Update action: push new data to values and pop the oldest*/}
);
```

***In conclusion***, you may execute **UPDATE_STAT_1** first, then **check the execution result** to decide if you need to execute **UPDATE_STAT_2** like this(pseudocode):

```
exe_result = run(UPDATE_STAT_1); // Run UPDATE_STAT_1
if(exe_result.nMatched == 0 && exe_result.nModified == 0) {
    run(UPDATE_STAT_2); // Check the count and Run UPDATE_STAT_2
}
```

This is my approach for Merging Query(1st) and Evaluation(2nd). I don't know how to merge all of above code into one statement.

#### III. Update part: Merge Push(3rd)/Pop(4th)/Increase(5th)?

I had tried in my local, you can put **Push** & **Increase** into one statement:

```
db.test.update(
    {device: 'deviceId1', count: {$lt: 90}},
    {
        $push: {values: { "ts" : "1471077454988", "measureData" : 39 }},
        $inc : {count: 1}
    }
);
```

It is legal to do Push(3rd) & Increase(5th) at the same time. But if you want to push & pop the array:

```
db.test.update(
    {device: 'deviceId1', count: {$gte: 90}},
    {
        $pop: {values: -1},
        $push: {values: { "ts" : "1471077454911", "measureData" : 40 }}
    }
);
```

you will get error:

```
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 16837,
        "errmsg" : "Cannot update 'values' and 'values' at the same time"
    }
})
```

which means you can't do push & pop on values at the same time. For this, I found this explanation:

> The issue is that MongoDB doesn’t allow multiple operations on the
>   same property in the same update call. This means that the two
>   operations must happen in two individually atomic operations.

***So. In conclusion***, it is not able to merge Push(3rd)/Pop(4th)/Increase(5th) into one statement.

#### IV. Summary

Based on the samples above, the Query(1st) and Evaluation(2nd) can not be merged, the Push(3rd)/Pop(4th)/Increase(5th) can not be merged neither. So you might do this in traditional way. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is big effort to answer my question. I put forward this question is because time series data is a common requirement for many projects. I try to find better solution than tradtional one. I did not expect that you put so much effort. I share my solution in the  question part 2. Big thans again!

Comment: I have experience on MongoDB with Node.JS only, not with Java. But I think  they are the same in low level implementation - they use the same commands provided by MongoDB.